# JQ: Using variable for dot notation path

Tags: json, variables, path, jq

Is it possible to use a variable to hold a dot notation path? (I'm probably not using the correct term.)

For example, given the following json:

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "names": {
        "given": "Alice",
        "family": "Smith"
      },
      "id": 47
    },
    {
      "id": 42
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to construct something like:

`.names.given as $ng | .people[] | select(.id==47) | ($ng)`

and output "Alice"?

The idea is to allow easier modification of a complex expression. I've tried various parens and quotes with increasing literal results ('.names.given' and '$ng')

Comment: Alternatively, you may embed your path in a function instead of a variable, i.e. `def ng: .names.given;` then use it like `select(.id==47) | ng`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no and yes: as you've seen, once you write an expression such as `.names.given as $ng`, $ng holds the JSON values, not the path.

But jq does support `path expressions` in the form of arrays of strings and/or non-negative integers. These can be used to access values in conjunction with the built-in `getpath/1`.

So you could, for example, write something along the lines of:

```
["names", "given"] as $ng
| .people[]
| select(.id==47)
| getpath($ng)
```

### Converting jq paths to JSON arrays

It's possible to convert a "dot notation" path into an "array path" using `path/1`; e.g. the assignment to $ng above could be written as:

```
(null | path(.names.given)) as $ng
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question and the example you provided seems very confusing to me. The jist that I got is that you want to assign a name to a value obtained from dot notation and then use it at a later point in time.

See if this is of any help -

```
.people | map(select(.id = 47))[0].names.given as $ng | $ng
```